# Creating a procedure for logging on, in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I've been asked to create a procedure when the user can introduce their username and password, I should be able to match the user info according to whats in the "shopper" table. I have created a procedure that seems correct to me, but when I run the procedure inserting a valid username and valid password, it tells me that:`it cannot be used as an assignment target`

Here I will post my code to see if I could get any help.
By the way as part of question I'm supposed to use a IN OUT parameter, the procedure receives the username and password from the user and return the full name when log on has been matched. If the user doesn't enter the right information a variable holding "INVALID" is supposed display the message. 
Does anybody would know what is the error here, I've been spending a good amount of hours trying to figure this out but I still can't.
I appreciate any help.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE member_ck_sp
  (p_user IN VARCHAR2,
   p_pass IN OUT VARCHAR2)
 IS
   lv_check_txt VARCHAR2(10) := 'INVALID';
   lv_fullname_txt VARCHAR2(25);
 CURSOR MEMBER_CUR IS
  SELECT firstname, lastname, cookie, username, password
  FROM bb_shopper
  WHERE username = p_user
  AND password = p_pass;
BEGIN
      FOR REC_CUR IN MEMBER_CUR LOOP
        IF p_user = rec_cur.username AND p_pass = rec_cur.password THEN
          p_pass := rec_cur.firstname || ' ' || rec_cur.lastname;
          dbms_output.put_line('Welcome: ' || p_pass || 'Cookie: ' || rec_cur.cookie);
        ELSE
          dbms_output.put_line(lv_check_txt);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
END member_ck_sp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure compiles and somewhat works as is: you're modifying `p_pass` but since it is an `IN OUT` parameter this should work.

However, you can't call this function with a constant:

```
SQL> begin member_ck_sp('ab', 'xx'); end;
  2  /

ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00363: expression 'xx' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Because a constant can't be used as an `OUT` parameter. You can call the procedure with variables:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_user VARCHAR2(100) := 'ab';
  3     l_password VARCHAR2(100) := 'xx';
  4  BEGIN
  5     member_ck_sp(l_user, l_password);
  6  END;
  7  /

Welcome: a bCookie: 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

However, it doesn't make a lot of sense to update the password parameter with another value that is not a password. I suggest you modify the procedure so that the password is not updated, use a local variable instead:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE member_ck_sp(p_user IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                           p_pass IN VARCHAR2) IS
  3     lv_check_txt    VARCHAR2(10) := 'INVALID';
  4     lv_fullname_txt VARCHAR2(25);
  5     CURSOR MEMBER_CUR IS
  6        SELECT firstname, lastname, cookie, username, password
  7          FROM bb_shopper
  8         WHERE username = p_user
  9           AND password = p_pass;
 10  BEGIN
 11     FOR REC_CUR IN MEMBER_CUR LOOP
 12        IF p_user = rec_cur.username AND p_pass = rec_cur.password THEN
 13           lv_fullname_txt := rec_cur.firstname || ' ' || rec_cur.lastname;
 14           dbms_output.put_line('Welcome: ' || lv_fullname_txt
 15                                || 'Cookie: ' || rec_cur.cookie);
 16        ELSE
 17           dbms_output.put_line(lv_check_txt);
 18        END IF;
 19     END LOOP;
 20  END member_ck_sp;
 21  /

Procedure created

SQL> begin member_ck_sp('ab', 'xx'); end;
  2  /

Welcome: a bCookie: 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Also don't forget to hash the password, it looks like your model is storing the password in clear text ([don't do that](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQFjAC&url=http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html&ei=s5aHUceiCouEhQfYhICQDA&usg=AFQjCNErHpsEDn4idifgNR0AvuWgBolGrA&sig2=GKp0O5uGOCQaptycvSEO_w&bvm=bv.45960087,d.ZG4)).

Comment: thanks for your replay. But even though i have tried what you just mentioned, nothing happens, I still get the same error, any other sugestions????

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to update the password parameter. See my updated answer or [@M.Heydari](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2039695/m-heydari)'s answer to change your procedure declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE member_ck_sp
  (p_user IN VARCHAR2,
   p_pass IN VARCHAR2,
   p_FullName OUT VARCHAR2)
 IS
 failour_msg varchar2(50) := 'INVALID USER NAME';
 CURSOR MEMBER_CUR IS
  SELECT firstname, lastname, cookie, username, password
  FROM bb_shopper
  WHERE upper(username) = upper(p_user)
  AND password = p_pass;
BEGIN
     p_FullName := failour_msg;
      FOR REC_CUR IN MEMBER_CUR LOOP        
          p_FullName := rec_cur.firstname || ' ' || rec_cur.lastname;
          dbms_output.put_line('Welcome: ' || p_pass || 'Cookie: ' || rec_cur.cookie);                          
      END LOOP;
if p_FullName =  failour_msg then 
  dbms_output.put_line(failour_msg);
  end if;
END member_ck_sp;
```